# Почему не очищается очередь Rabbit MQ с помощью amqpAdmin.purgeQueue, если все сообщения в статусе ready?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Все сообщения в статусе ready. Пробую очистить очередь с помощью

```
amqpAdmin.purgeQueue("workOut", false);
```

Очередь не очищается. Почему?